# Expected exception message not displaying in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write a program with database connectivity and exception handling in PHP.  If I insert an incorrect username then it should display its corresponding error message, and if I insert the incorrect database it should display its corresponding error message.

But in the following program whether I insert incorrect database or incorrect username it only displays the message "Could not connect to database".

```
<?php
   $hostname = "localhost";
   $username = "root1";
   $password = "";
   $database = "php_thenewboston";
   $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
   $conn_db = mysqli_select_db($conn,$database);
   class ServerException extends Exception{}  
   class DatabaseException extends Exception{}
   try{
       if(!$conn){
           throw new ServerException('Could not connect to server.');
       }elseif(!$conn_db){
           throw new DatabaseException('Could not connect to database.');
       }else{
           echo "Connected.";
       }
   }catch(ServerException $ex){
       echo "Error :".$ex->getMessage();        
   }catch(DatabaseException $ex){
       echo "Error :".$ex->getMessage();
   }
?>
```

I am a beginner in PHP.
Please comment below for any query.

**EDIT**

As asked by @Hatef
Below is the `var_dump` of `$conn` when username is incorrect, password is correct and database name is correct

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["client_info"]=>
  string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 241ae00989d1995ffcbbf63d579943635faf9972 $"
  ["client_version"]=>
  int(50012)
  ["connect_errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_error"]=>
  NULL
  ["errno"]=>
  int(1044)
  ["error"]=>
  string(68) "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'php_thenewboston'"
  ["error_list"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["errno"]=>
      int(1044)
      ["sqlstate"]=>
      string(5) "42000"
      ["error"]=>
      string(68) "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'php_thenewboston'"
    }
  }
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["host_info"]=>
  string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP"
  ["info"]=>
  NULL
  ["insert_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["server_info"]=>
  string(21) "5.5.5-10.1.16-MariaDB"
  ["server_version"]=>
  int(50505)
  ["stat"]=>
  string(132) "Uptime: 1072  Threads: 1  Questions: 16  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 18  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 11  Queries per second avg: 0.014"
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  ["protocol_version"]=>
  int(10)
  ["thread_id"]=>
  int(9)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Below is the var_dump of `$conn` when the username is correct, password is correct and database name is incorrect.

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["client_info"]=>
  string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 241ae00989d1995ffcbbf63d579943635faf9972 $"
  ["client_version"]=>
  int(50012)
  ["connect_errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_error"]=>
  NULL
  ["errno"]=>
  int(1049)
  ["error"]=>
  string(36) "Unknown database 'php_thenewboston1'"
  ["error_list"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["errno"]=>
      int(1049)
      ["sqlstate"]=>
      string(5) "42000"
      ["error"]=>
      string(36) "Unknown database 'php_thenewboston1'"
    }
  }
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["host_info"]=>
  string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP"
  ["info"]=>
  NULL
  ["insert_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["server_info"]=>
  string(21) "5.5.5-10.1.16-MariaDB"
  ["server_version"]=>
  int(50505)
  ["stat"]=>
  string(132) "Uptime: 1417  Threads: 1  Questions: 18  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 18  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 11  Queries per second avg: 0.012"
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  ["protocol_version"]=>
  int(10)
  ["thread_id"]=>
  int(10)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Comment: Check the result of `mysqli_select_db()` **before** you try to call `mysqli_select_db()` with its results...

Comment: Put your mysqli_connect and mysqli_select_db inside of your try block, it will save a few headaches.

Comment: I recommand using `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of pages, so PHP will throw back very helpful messages. EDIT: plus  `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` when dealing with DB

Comment: @AlexHowansky When username is correct `mysqli_select_db()` returns 1 and if the username is incorrect it returns null.

Comment: try modifying just 2 lines -> `$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password); $conn_db = mysqli_select_db($conn,$database);` with this -> `$mysqli = mysqli_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password", "$database"); if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Error: no connexion allowed : " . mysqli_connect_error($mysqli); }` and see what comes out (keep error_reporting ON too)

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump `of `$conn` to see what it's in it in different scenarios?

Comment: See my answer for the error catching mechanism for each query. Just use the try/catch setup with the `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` option on initializing the PDO DB connection

Answer (score 1):

By Default, mysql automatically throws the exception. To throw the exception manually, you need to write the below line at top of file
This will throw exception even on mysqli_connect. So you need to add the connect method in try block.
`mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

UPDATE: In your case, don't write the above line, change the hostname & you will get the server error in your catch block.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it gives the same message.

Comment: @RK try changing the hostname

Comment: Gives the following error `Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known`

Comment: @RK updated the answer. Remove the `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` & change the hostname & you will get the desired answer

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, you sounds a good oops programmer. Well every programming language has its own set of rules & standards.

Lets go through your code

```
   $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
   $conn_db = mysqli_select_db($conn,$database);
   class ServerException extends Exception{}  
   class DatabaseException extends Exception{}
```

Here you are trying to initiate a connection. Then in your try catch block you are checking the connectivity.

Put you connection also in your try catch block & catch the exception.

For example :

```
try
{
    if ($db = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db))
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using mysqli_connect, you will be able to pass database name within that same function so for connection purpose you don't need to wait for mysqli_select_db()

There are many error code which you will get after connection attempt and based on that you will be able to specify proper message.

I have updated your code and conditions so you will get idea

```
<?php
       $hostname = "localhost";
       $username = "root1";
       $password = "";
       $database = "php_thenewboston";
       $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
       $error = mysqli_connect_errno();
       //$conn_db = mysqli_select_db($conn,$database);
       class ServerException extends Exception{}  
       class DatabaseException extends Exception{}
       try{
           if($error == 1044){
               throw new ServerException('Could not connect to server. Check Username');
           }elseif($error == 1045){
               throw new DatabaseException('Could not connect to server. Check Password');
            }elseif($error == 1049){
               throw new DatabaseException('Could not connect to database. Check Database Name');
           }else{
               echo "Connected.";
           }
       }catch(ServerException $ex){
           echo "Error :".$ex->getMessage();        
       }catch(DatabaseException $ex){
           echo "Error :".$ex->getMessage();
       }
?>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the PDO statements. The underneath example will tell you what error occurs when you use the try/catch setup.

Connect PDO with underneath code:

```
$mysqli_pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    ));
```

Then wrap your SQL in the try/catch setup like shown below:

```
try {
    //$mysqli_pdo->beginTransaction(); If you need transaction
    $sql = $mysqli_pdo->prepare("[YOUR SQL]");
    $sql->bindValue(1, $INT_VAL, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindValue(2, $STR_VAL, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->execute();
    //$mysqli_pdo->commit(); Don't forget if you use transaction
    }
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    //$mysqli_pdo->rollBack(); Don't forget if you use transaction
    exit();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following for connection..

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "php_thenewboston");


try{ 
      if(!$mysqli){
           throw new ServerException('Could not connect to server.');
       }else{
           echo "Connected.";
       }
   }catch(ServerException $ex){
       echo "Error :".$ex->getMessage();        
   }catch(DatabaseException $ex){
       echo "Error :".$ex->getMessage();
   }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The MySQLi extension provides error information.

If `$conn == false`, call `mysqli_connect_error()` after to get your error message.

If you want to use your own message, `mysqli_connect_errno()` will return the error code, which you can use to handle it how you want.

From the PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_query($link, "SET a=1")) {
    printf("Errorcode: %d\n", mysqli_errno($link));
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```